# How can I Make a comparison of the content of the list

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a list with words in it. I want to compare each letter in each word with the corresponding letter, and the largest one is printed first, and so on...

Comment: what is largest one in a letter? Do you mean A-Z? A being the lowest and Z highest?

Comment: Yes First, the largest letter is printed, then the smallest letter, and so on

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: I have a list of five names. I want to compare the first letter of the first name with the first letter of the rest of the names, and so on with the second and third letters, and then print the largest letter of the first letters from highest to lowest, then the second and third letters, and so on

Comment: use substring(0,1) to get the first letter of a word and compare using compareTo method of a string. Please check the official flutter documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/compareTo.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list using Collections and get the required string.  0
index will have smallest and last index will have largest. If  you want
vice versa you can use list in reverse order.

```
 val modelList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    modelList.add("Rock")
    modelList.add("Undertaker")
    modelList.add("Sting")
    modelList.add("Austin")
    modelList.add("John Cena")

    Collections.sort(modelList,
        Comparator<Any?> { str, str1 -> 
    str.toString().compareTo(str1.toString()) })
```

//After this call you modelList  will  be sorted as [Austin, John Cena, Rock, Sting, Undertaker]

Comment: Can you give me the full code with the list?

Comment: You are using  Kotlin in Android ?

Comment: I'm learning Dart and using vscode